# How do I tag a local docker image with ansible docker_image module?

Tags: image, docker, ansible

I'm building a local docker image and I'd like to tag it, but I have no idea how the `repository` field should be filled for a docker image I just built locally.

Is tagging local images even possible with the `docker_image` module?

Comment: What do you mean by the repository field? It should be as simple as: docker tag java:6 some_image:some_version

Comment: @Nauraushaun I'm talking about ansible. I know how to tag use the cli

Comment: Ooh sorry, the terminology is similar!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find out that the `repository` of the `docker_image` module is just the name of the image when it's locally built.

This is how you first build the image with tag `latest` and then add a tag to it.

```
- name: Build docker image
  become: yes
  docker_image:
    path: /tmp/foo
    name: foo
    state: present

- name: Tag docker image
  become: yes
  docker_image:
    name: foo
    repository: foo
    tag: "{{ version.stdout }}"
    state: present
```

Comment: Cannot make it work. The second docker_images command does nothing. This command is not easy to use because the result is a combination of all parameters. I rather prefer have an action verb like "build" or "tag".

Comment: if you are also in trouble with this module: https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/issues/5511

Answer (score 11):

Seems that there is better solution with [`docker_image`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/docker/docker_image_module.html):

```
tasks:
  - name: build_image
    docker_image:
      name: test_img:latest     # Name of image, may be with repo path.
      path: .
      state: present
    register: image_build
  
  - name: tag_version
    docker_image:
      name: test_img:latest     # Equal to name in build task.
      repository: test_img:1.2  # New tag there.
      pull: no
      state: present
    when: image_build.changed
```

Effect:

```
    $ docker images
    REPOSITORY   TAG       IMAGE ID            CREATED              SIZE
    test_img     1.2       ab14e8cce7ef        9 seconds ago        142MB
    test_img     latest    ab14e8cce7ef        9 seconds ago        142MB
```

Works also with pushing to repo (need to change name to full repo path).

Comment: Works, but feels a slight bit hacky. I wish you could just use the `tag` parameter to add a tag to an existing tagged image if you provide the original tag as part of the `name` parameter.

Comment: Not working for me for some reason. TypeError: argument of type 'bool' is not iterable

Answer (score 7):

You can build and tag in one command. If you want it to stay local, you can't include a repository in the name (no `/`). The tag is just the equivalent of "latest". So the result looks something like:

```
  - name: 'Build an image with a tag'
    docker_image:
      path: .
      name: ansible-module
      tag: v1
      state: present
```

And the result will look like:

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY                  TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
ansible-module              v1                  39be0dcc8dfa        2 minutes ago       1.093 MB
```

If you want to include your registry url or repository name (docker hub login) and don't want to automatically push after building, I don't believe you can use this Ansible plugin.

---

Update, for an additional tag, you can do:

```
  - name: 'Build an image'
    docker_image:
      path: .
      name: ansible-module
      tag: v1
      state: present
    register: docker_build

  - name: 'Retag image'
    shell: docker tag ansible-module:v1 ansible-module:dev
    when: docker_build.changed
```

Comment: Right, but I need the build to create the `latest` tag and then I need to add a version tag

Comment: I suspect this is beyond the scope of the module, you can always check the result, and if changed, run a shell to do the docker tag command. I'll update with an example.